# Organize a file

Tags: linux, shell, files, awk

I have the following file:

```
name   id   alello chr  pos snp    
s1     215     a    1   11  a215    
s1     216     a    1   11  a216    
s1     217     a    1   11  a217    
s1     218     a    1   11  a218    
s2     215     b    2   22  b215    
s2     216     b    2   22  b216    
s2     217     b    2   22  b217    
s2     218     b    2   22  b218
```

and I need that file be this way:

```
snp allelo  chr pos 215     216      217    218    
s1     a    1   11  a215    a216    a217    a218    
s2     b    2   22  b215    b216    b217    b218
```

Comment: wellcome to U&L, what have you try so far ?

Comment: Hi man, nice to meet you , unfortunately, in this case, I don't know where begin,

Comment: We need more information. Specifically, how do name, chr, alello, and pos relate to each other? In your example, it seems that for all rows of s1, alello=1, chr=1, and pos=11. Likewise for s2, alello=b, chr=2, and pos=22. Is this the case for the entire file? E.g. do the s3 records all contain alello=c, chr=3 and pos=33? Or is everything variable? If so, please provide more example rows for the desired output.

Comment: Thanks man, but I resolve this question...

Comment: Copy and paste the "need the file be this way" section into your file.  Voila!  :)

Comment: Cross posted to, and resolved on: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36358665/4957508

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==1{h=$1 OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $5; next} 
            {a[$1]=(($1 in a)?(a[$1] OFS $NF):($3 OFS $4 OFS $5 OFS $6));
             if(!($2 in b)) {h=h OFS $2; b[$2]}} 
        END{print h; for(k in a) print k,a[k]}' file | column -t

name  alello  chr  pos  215   216   217   218
s1    a       1    11   a215  a216  a217  a218
s2    b       2    22   b215  b216  b217  b218
```

I didn't solve this problem. Credit to karakfa.